# Complex Analysis Qualifying Exam Problem Regarding Taylor Series and Normal Convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

I am studying for a qualifying exam on Gamelin's Complex Analysis Chapters 1-11 and am stuck on the following past exam question:

Let $\phi(n): \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\phi(n)}{n}=0$. Let $F$ be the family of analytic functions $f$ defined on neighborhoods of $0$ such that the coefficients of the Taylor series $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ satisfy $|a_n| \le e^{\phi (n)}$. Show that the Taylor series of $f \in F$ converges on the unit disk $D$ and the family $F$ is normal on $D$.

My goal was to compute the radius of convergence to be 1. I attempted to look at $f'(z)$ since that has the same radius of convergence as $f$ and was hoping to get a bound on $n|a_n|$ using $\phi$.

The family being normal should follow after showing $f$ converges since $f$ is the uniform limit of continuous functions and thus continuous and bounded on compact sets. Montel's theorem shows every sequence has a normally convergent subsequence on $D$.

Could someone give me a hint on how to show $f$ converges on $D$?

Comment: Assume $0<r<1$. And $|z|=r$. Then $|a_nz^n|^{1/n}\leq e^{\phi(n)/n}r\to r<1$. So, you have (absolute) convergence for all radii less than $1$. Therefore, the radius of convergence is at least $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: you have to be careful about normality since $nz$ which are polynomials do not form a normal family on the unit disc; Montel theorem requires (locally) uniform bounds on the whole family; fixing $r<1$, then for $|z| \le r$ we have $|f(z)|=|\sum a_n z^n| \le \sum e^{\phi(n)}r^n$ so fixing some $n_r$ for which $\phi (n) < n|\log r|/2, n \ge n_r$ one has $|f(z)| \le \sum e^{(n\log r)/2}+\sum_{n<n_r}e^{\phi(n)}r^n \le K_r+\sum_{n<n_r}e^{\phi(n)}r^n$ where $K_r$ is the geometric series $\sum q^n, q=e^{(\log r)/2}$, giving you the uniform boundness on $|z| \le r$ required for Montel

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. My argument would only ensure local bounds for each element, not a uniform bound on the whole family. Thank you again!